# Proving that a regular value of a smooth function isn't in the boundary of the counter-domain

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose $X$ is a manifold without boundary and $Y$ is a manifold.

Suppose there is a smooth function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and we are given a $y \in Y$ such that $y$ is a regular value of $f$ and $f^{-1}(y) \neq \emptyset$.

Then $y$ is not in the boundary of $Y$.

I believe there would be some contradiction with the boundary of $X$ being void.

This is somewhat weird because i can't seem to find any connection between these hypothesis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $X$ is of dimension $m$ and $Y$ is of dimension $n$. If $y$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a properly embedded submanifold of $X$ with dimension $m-n$. Call this submanifold $S$.

Given a point $p$ in $S$, this means that there are coordinate charts $(U, \varphi)$ in $X$ containing $p$ and $(V, \psi)$ in $Y$ containing $f(p)$ such that the local coordinate representation for $f$ is of the form:
$$(\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1})(x^1, \ldots, x^{m-n}, x^{m-n+1}, \ldots, x^{m})=(x^{m-n+1}, x^{m-n+2}, \ldots, x^m)$$
In particular, $\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ maps the last $n$ coordinates in $\varphi(U)$ diffeomorphically onto their image in $\psi(V)$. If $f(p)$ is a boundary point, then this is a diffeomorphism between an open $n$-ball and the image of a boundary chart in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: I believe this, but can you tell me what results states that there have to be such cordinates?

Comment: This is known as the [rank theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&lpg=PA83&ots=j_PqS10dWY&dq=rank%20theorem%20smooth%20manifolds&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Connor Doesn't use of the rank theorem require that $f$ is of constant rank on a neighborhood of $y$, but we cannot assume that such a neighborhood exists precisely because we are unsure if $y$ lies on the boundary?