# Regular values on boundary of smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth compact manifold without boundary and $Y$ be a smooth compact manifold with boundary $\delta Y$ where $\dim X = \dim Y$. Suppose $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is smooth.

As shown in this question:

[Proving that a regular value of a smooth function isn't in the boundary of the counter-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721686/proving-that-a-regular-value-of-a-smooth-function-isnt-in-the-boundary-of-the-c)

there are no regular values $y \in \delta Y$ with $f(x)=y$ for some $x \in X$.

My question is: Are there any regular values $y \in \delta Y$ or does $\delta Y$ not contain any regular values at all? Either way, how to prove that there exist / don't exist regular values in the boundary $\delta Y$ of $Y$?

Remark: I'm considering a (possibly regular) value $y \in \delta Y$ with $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset$.

Comment: I changed dim \hspace{1 mm} X to \dim X, so it appears as $\dim X$ rather than $dim \hspace{1 mm} X$.  That is standard usage.  Just as with \log, \sin,\det, \max, \sup, etc. the "hspace" both to the left and to the right of $\dim$ is built in. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You're asking whether $\partial X \subset f(Y)$, necessarily?

Comment: Not quiet. I'm asking if either 1. there are regular values $y$ on the boundary of $Y$ where $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset$ or 2. there are no regular values on the boundary of $Y$ (taking into consideration that there are no regular values $y \in \delta Y$ with $f(x)=y$ for some $x \in X$).

Comment: I presume there's a typo in the first line. You mean to say that $X$ is a compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: That is correct, I edited that.

Answer (score 0):

The only regular values of $f$ in $\partial Y$ are those $y$ with $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$. For if $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ is a point so that $df_x$ has maximal rank, $f$ is necessarily a local diffeomorphism (and a neighborhood of a boundary point is not diffeomorphic — or even homeomorphic — to an open set in $\Bbb R^n$).

Some good examples to think of are maps $S^2\to D^2$. You can project down directly, and then the equator maps to the boundary and consists of all singular points. You can map everything to a point. You can map to a small disk inside $D^2$, or you can slide that small disk over so that it overlaps part of $\partial D^2$.

Comment: Can you give any proof that there actually exist one or more regular values of $f$ in $\delta Y$ [necessarily with $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$]? Or is there some "trivial" reason that they exist? I know that the regular values are dense in $int(Y)$, whereas I don't know how to prove the existence of regular values on $\delta Y$.

Comment: No. For my first example, all of $\partial Y$ is hit and none is a regular value. Draw pictures of these examples.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why does $df_x$ having maximal rank imply that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism? Isn't proving this statement equivalent to the original question or am I missing something?

Comment: @JonRayner: Once you're in coordinate charts, this is the inverse function theorem. To convince yourself of what's going on, I recommend you try to create a map $f$ (a neighborhood of) $0$ in $\Bbb R^n$ to the upper half-space $\Bbb H^n$, with $0$ mapping to $0$. Now do it in such a way that the derivative at $0$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$. You can't. Proof: Consider a path $\gamma$ through $0$ orthogonal to the preimage of $T_0(\partial\Bbb H^n)$.  $\gamma$ must map to a curve that turns around at $0\in\partial\Bbb H^n$. What does that mean about the derivative $df_0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I was thinking that we could not use the inverse function theorem at the boundary (and also I missed that dim$X = $dim$Y$. I'm happy now, thanks